# Construct 2 functions as counterexamples

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

My textbook claims two propositions as follows:

(1) $f(x)>0$ is a continuous function, $\int_a^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ converges, $\int_a^{+\infty}f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x$ not necessarily converges;

(2) $f(x)>0$ is a continuous function, $\int_a^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ converges, we can not obtain $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$.

For (1), I have constructed a closed answer $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$, but it has countable infinite zero points; For(2), I haven't got a clue so far. Please tell me the answers and give a simplified proof if if's ok.

I suddenly realize I constructed wrongly for (1), $f(x)$ may be less than $0$, and I don't know how to construct a correct one.

Comment: It is easy to go from the case $f \geq 0$ to $f>0$. Just add $e^{-|x|}$ to your $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (2) let $g(x)=n^{2}(x-n)(n+\frac  1 {n^{2}} -x)$ for $n \leq x \leq n+\frac  1 {n^{2}}, n=1,2,...$. Make $g$ $0$ outside these intervals . [Draw a picture]. Then $g(n)=1$ for all $n$ but $\int_n^{n+\frac  1 {n^{2}}} g(x) dx \leq \frac  1{n^{2}}$ so $\int_1^{\infty} g(x)dx <\infty$. Take $f(x)=g(x)+e^{-|x|}$.

Answer (score 1):

For (2) consider a function with increasingly thin spikes centred at each positive integer.
So let $\phi(x)=e^{-x^2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$. Then $\phi$ has integral $1$ over $\Bbb R$ and
$a\phi(k(x-n))$ has integral $a/k$ and a spike of height $a$ at $n$. Consider
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\phi(k_n(x-n))$$
where we choose $a_n\to\infty$ and $k_n\to0$ rapidly enough to ensure $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx<\infty$. I think $a_n=n$ and $k_n=2^n$ should do it.